# Stepping through Linq statement tips

Tags: c#, linq, debugging

When I step through code and get to a linq statement, the stepping through process and the lines which are evaluated (and their order) are not the same as the code is written. I know this is to do with commands like yield etc.

My questions are:

1. What do I need to learn to understand why the code is debugged in the way it is (with Linq statements)?
2. What stepping through techniques are there for Linq statements?

Oh, and I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385795.aspx)

`Any query that compiles to an expression tree produces code that is beyond the control of the debugger.`

So you won't be able to fully debug the Linq query through Visual Studio Debugger.

**But**

there are few tool which can help for example `Linq Pad`

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#bkmk_steppingandlinq) also describes some techniques that can be used for debugging Linq statements

[This is another](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/) detailed article about debugging Linq

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any other method of debugging of the generated `IL code`, then using 
[Sos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx), on your binary. You can do everything (if not more) of then you're able to do in `VS debugging tools` (*may be a multithreading debugging stuff is better to do in VS*). But again, considering the `LINQ` code is not the code you see in your codefile, but the `IL code` generated at compile time, I would say, that, by me, this is the only possible way to  make `StepInto/Over/Out` on code like that.